# How do you check if the Second Dimension of a 2D array is null?

Tags: java, arrays

Lets say for example you have a 2D Array `field[60][]`.
How exactly can you check if the second part of the Array is null?
Is there any way to do something similiar like `if(field ==null)` but for the second dimension?

Comment: Sure, `if (field[0] == null) {`

Comment: There is no single second dimension.  You'd have to check if one (or all) of the rows of the first dimension are null.  (Note above Robert checked just one row; for your application it might be necessary to check all of them.)

Comment: field[0] == null gives me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Then your array was declared like `field[0][]` or similar.  Yes the second dimension could be of zero size in addition to null.

Answer (score 0):

Just for illustration purpose:

```
Integer field[][]=new Integer[2][]; 
        field[0]=new Integer[2]; //you can declare size for second dimension like this.
        if(field[0]==null) {   // do null checks
            System.out.println("field[0] is null");
        }if(field[1]==null) {
            System.out.println("field[1] is null");
        }
```

Output:

```
field[1] is null
```